# VSCode crashing Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS completely

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I had an input glitch where my keyboard shortcut to launch VSCode was permanently turned on for a good few minutes. I fixed it and restarted my PC as there was just an absurd number of windows open. After the restart when I try to launch VSCode my entire system crashes, I can move the mouse but cannot execute any commands or interact with windows, having htop running for example would just freeze and stop updating.

I have tried starting with disabled extensions, disabled GPU and limited RAM.

I have the logs from --verbose, the top part is shown below but it is a huge file so cant paste it all here, let me know if there are bits I should grab out.

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so: undefined symbol: g_date_time_format_iso8601
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so
[main 2021-09-13T13:27:22.226Z] Starting VS Code
[main 2021-09-13T13:27:22.228Z] from: /snap/code/73/usr/share/code/resources/app
[main 2021-09-13T13:27:22.228Z] args: {
  _: [],
  diff: false,
  add: false,
  goto: false,
  'new-window': false,
  'reuse-window': false,
  wait: false,
  help: false,
  'list-extensions': false,
  'show-versions': false,
  version: false,
  verbose: true,
  status: false,
  'prof-startup': false,
  'no-cached-data': false,
  'prof-v8-extensions': false,
  'disable-extensions': true,
  'disable-gpu': false,
  'max-memory': '12288mb',
  telemetry: false,
  debugRenderer: false,
  logExtensionHostCommunication: false,
  'skip-release-notes': false,
  'skip-welcome': false,
  'disable-telemetry': false,
  'disable-updates': false,
  'disable-keytar': false,
  'disable-workspace-trust': false,
  'disable-crash-reporter': false,
  'crash-reporter-id': '0393e851-0a7a-481a-9f88-2a32ca785539',
  'skip-add-to-recently-opened': false,
  'unity-launch': false,
  'open-url': false,
  'file-write': false,
  'file-chmod': false,
  'driver-verbose': false,
  force: false,
  'do-not-sync': false,
  trace: false,
  'force-user-env': false,
  'force-disable-user-env': false,
  'open-devtools': false,
  __sandbox: false,
  'no-proxy-server': false,
  'no-sandbox': false,
  nolazy: false,
  'force-renderer-accessibility': false,
  'ignore-certificate-errors': false,
  'allow-insecure-localhost': false,
  logsPath: '/home/MyUser/.config/Code/logs/20210913T142722'
}
[main 2021-09-13T13:27:22.229Z] Resolving machine identifier...
[main 2021-09-13T13:27:22.230Z] Resolved machine identifier: 25bca5857aa498c92d1f9b8898de7fb1272b6da130b2d5ac4d3934fafe7b550c
[main 2021-09-13T13:27:22.230Z] Main->SharedProcess#connect
[main 2021-09-13T13:27:22.246Z] update#setState idle
[main 2021-09-13T13:27:22.247Z] StorageMainService: creating global storage
[main 2021-09-13T13:27:22.247Z] lifecycle (main): phase changed (value: 2)
[main 2021-09-13T13:27:22.248Z] windowsManager#open
[main 2021-09-13T13:27:22.248Z] windowsManager#open pathsToOpen [
  {
    workspace: { id: '46ca490ef0f10bfae7c298f269044be1', uri: [g] },
    exists: true
  },
  {
    backupPath: '/home/MyUser/.config/Code/Backups/1631531462560',
    remoteAuthority: undefined
  },
  {## Heading ##
    backupPath: '/home/MyUser/.config/Code/Backups/1631531463212',
    remoteAuthority: undefined
  },
  {
    backupPath: '/home/MyUser/.config/Code/Backups/1631531463785',
    remoteAuthority: undefined
  },
  {
    backupPath: '/home/MyUser/.config/Code/Backups/1631531464197',
    remoteAuthority: undefined
  },
  ...
```

I appreciate any help with this I have no idea what has gone wrong, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it, seems obvious in hindsight, I just opened VSCode on a specific file rather than just launch it normally and let it load up the files it had open previously, so `code afile.txt.` rather than just `code`. This fixed my issue, hope it helps others.

Comment: VS Code made my desktop crash. Opening at a directory seems to work.